# Как авторизироваться и отправить запрос?

Tags: golang

Как я могу авторизироваться POST запросом и потом отправить GET запрос на авторизированную страницу?

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    //"golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    //"net/http/cookiejar"
    "net/url"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {


    client := http.Client{/*Jar: jar*/}

    resp, err := client.PostForm("https://www.site/user/login", url.Values{
        "username": {"email@gmail.com"},
        "password": {"qwerty123"},
        "postcode": {"010002"},
        "lastname": {""},
        "magicWord":{"asdsdsdxx-dddsdcc12--32-2-1--1-xx"},
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))

    //отправляется GET запрос, возвращается body и идет парсинг страницы
    ...

}
```

Страница станет доступна только после авторизации, а если я создам новый объект `http.Get()` у меня страница уже не будет доступна так как нужно будет повторная авторизация, то есть мне нужно держать сессию, без всяких переадресаций на localhost и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С куки пробовали? Мне помогло

```
cookieJar, _ := cookiejar.New(nil)
client := &http.Client{Jar: cookieJar}
```

Дальше все как у вас